# Google Column Chart with string labels

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I did this chart with Adobe Flex and I have to redo it with Javascript:

[image]

I've found Google Chart Tools, but after some investigation, I don't know if I can have string labels at the vertical column.

Do you know how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: do you want a label at the bottom of each bar ?

Comment: I'd like to have the labels at the left, exactly where the different levels are, but I don't know how to put them. Any idea?

Comment: do you want a label for each bar or a label for each level? If you want labels for the levels, it just added automatically. You just have to specify the bar headers data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want the labels on the Y axis or on the column itself although **Highcharts.js** does that and pretty much anything you want, check out this demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels